# Add delete button to datagrid that are set to AutoGenerateColumns?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in WPF that is auto generate it's column from a database table:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = connect2DB();
SqlDataAdapter adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable", sqlCon);
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Here is where I try to add the Delete Button to the Data Grid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" HName="dataGrid1" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowEditEnding="dataGrid1_RowEditEnding">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Remove Row" Command="Delete"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

This does not work and it say **{"Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."}**

I also tried the following code:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Src}" x:Name="Grid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Junk"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Which works but it doesn't generate a button, as far as I can tell, you can only generate a check box, a text box, or a hyper link.  How do I generate a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First exmple should work but you forgot about `DataGrid.Columns`. It should be:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn ...>
```

without that WPF assumes that you're creating items